# smbclient gives error NT_STATUS_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND and NetBIOS over TCP disabled

Tags: 16.04, mount, windows, samba, smb

I am trying to mount a shared folder on my jetson tx1.
on linux side, I am using ubuntu 16.04. the shared folder is on a windows server 2019.

the jetson is connected to the domain using wifi, the windows using ethernet.

on windows, I have enabled ethernet netbios over tcp:
[image]

on ubuntu:

```
smbclient -L myipadress -U myidonthedomain -W mydomain -m SMB3
```

it returns:

> Domain=[mydomain] OS=[] Server=[] list of folder etc ... on my windows
>   computer. Connection to myipaddress failed (Error
>   NT_STATUS_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND) NetBIOS over TCP disabled -- no
>   workgroup available.

if I try a mount:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=myusername,domain=domainname,sec=ntlmv2,vers=3.0 //windowsip/sharedfolder/ /mnt/test/
```

I get the error:

> Unknown vers= option specified:3.0

I don't know what to try now ...
any idea ?